# Sql update on phpmyadmin with having count and group by statement

Tags: mysql, sql, mariadb

Good afternoon i have a table with duplicated id_products  with primary id.
So i used a query to only displays 1 row of each id_product preventing the duplicated one as below.

```
select * 
from prstshp_stock_available2 
where reference like '%-R' and
 reference <> '%-R'
 GROUP BY id_product HAVING COUNT(*) = 1;
```

so i have fltered the data and now i want to update those rows quantity with a math operation on the update but only those filtered rows, have tried something like this:

```
UPDATE prstshp_stock_available2 
set quantity = (quantity/imultiply)-1 
where (select * 
     from prstshp_stock_available2 
     where reference like '%-R' and 
     reference <> '%-R'
 GROUP BY id_product HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```

, but it wont do anything.

Can you please check this and help me with the correct update query?

Thanks and have a good day!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In aggregate queries, never use `SELECT *`. MySQL allows such a query with its [`ONLY_GROUP_ON`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) setting turned off but it is not valid SQL (an unfortunate disservice to newcomers of SQL). Once corrected, use `IN` clause to condition the `UPDATE` query:

```sql
UPDATE prstshp_stock_available2 
SET quantity = (quantity/imultiply)-1 
WHERE id_product IN
  (SELECT id_product 
   FROM prstshp_stock_available2 
   WHERE reference LIKE '%-R' 
     AND reference <> '%-R'
   GROUP BY id_product 
   HAVING COUNT(*) = 1)
```